# Why is this Rcpp code not faster than pure R?

Tags: r, rcpp

## Setting up

I tried some R and Rcpp benchmarks with Fibonacci numbers.

### Pure R

We use the `fibR` function for the code that was written in pure R.

```
fibR <- function(n) {
    if (n < 2)
       n
    else
       fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
}
```

### Rcpp

We use another `fib` function for the code written in Rcpp.

```
library(Rcpp)

Rcpp::cppFunction('int fib(int x) {
    if((x < 2)) 
       return(x);
    else 
       return(fib(x-1) + fib(x-2));
   }')
```

---

## The results

Here are the results according to several benchmarks tests.

```
library(rbenchmark)
```

After that, I did several tests.

```
benchmark(fib(30), fibR(30))[,1:3]
      test replications elapsed
1  fib(30)          100    0.46
2 fibR(30)          100    0.45
```

```
benchmark(fib(31), fibR(31))[,1:3]
      test replications elapsed
1  fib(31)          100    0.77
2 fibR(31)          100    0.80
```

```
benchmark(fib(32), fibR(32))[,1:3]
      test replications elapsed
1  fib(32)          100    1.37
2 fibR(32)          100    1.33
```

```
benchmark(fib(33), fibR(33))[,1:3]
      test replications elapsed
1  fib(33)          100    1.88
2 fibR(33)          100    2.02
```

```
benchmark(fib(34), fibR(34))[,1:3]
      test replications elapsed
1  fib(34)          100    3.09
2 fibR(34)          100    3.26
```

```
benchmark(fib(35), fibR(35))[,1:3]
      test replications elapsed
1  fib(35)          100    5.57
2 fibR(35)          100    5.60
```

```
benchmark(fib(36), fibR(36))[,1:3]
      test replications elapsed
1  fib(36)          100    8.95
2 fibR(36)          100    8.51
```

```
benchmark(fib(37), fibR(37))[,1:3]
      test replications elapsed
1  fib(37)          100   16.94
2 fibR(37)          100   14.47
```

```
benchmark(fib(38), fibR(38))[,1:3]
      test replications elapsed
1  fib(38)          100   22.92
2 fibR(38)          100   23.67
```

```
benchmark(fib(39), fibR(39))[,1:3]
      test replications elapsed
1  fib(39)          100   35.80
2 fibR(39)          100   38.83
```

I would expect that the Rcpp code is steadily faster than the equivalent R code, but no – it is sometimes slower!

Why does it work like this, and what am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When something can't be true you should check closely what is going on :)

Here your R function *called your C++ function* as you were not careful about where `fib()` was coming from.  A repaired, more explicit version follow.

#### Code

```
fibR <- function(n) {
    if (n < 2)
        n
    else
        fibR(n - 1) + fibR(n - 2)
}

library(Rcpp)
Rcpp::cppFunction('int fibRcpp(int x) {
   if ((x < 2))
       return(x);
   else
       return(fibRcpp(x-1) + fibRcpp(x-2));
}')

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(fibRcpp(30), fibR(30))[,1:3]
```

#### Output

```
         test replications elapsed
2    fibR(30)          100  80.846
1 fibRcpp(30)          100   0.153
```

This is a rather well-studied example. Look at the directory [examples/Misc/](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/tree/master/inst/examples/Misc) in your Rcpp installation for examples last updated years ago.  Also look at [prior questions here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brcpp%5D+fibonacci).